# How can i check that media element is play file or not?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

i want to play an audio or video file, and i made this but i do not know how i can check whether media element is playing file or not?
Like using same button for Pause and Play how i can know that media is also playing file or not?
i use below code to play the file

```
mediaElement1.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
                mediaElement1.Source = new Uri("C:/test.wma", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                mediaElement1.Play();
```

And one more thing i know how to play file in media element by code. I want to to design media element UI. how i can design this for both video and audio files? what properties should enable and what should be disable.

Answer (score 0):

Last I checked you can't unless you are using Silverlight:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189079(v=vs.95).aspx

I have an application using .Net 4 and as far I can remember you cannot verify if it is playing, stopped, paused, etc.

This is what you can do with .Net 4:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement(v=vs.100).aspx

Compared with Silverlight:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement(v=vs.95).aspx